# Regex Replace with Variable

Tags: javascript, regex

This may be the silliest question I'm asking But I already wasted nearly 30 mins to get this done and thought to ask from you guys.

What basically this code needs to do is just replace the `str` value if it's in the list (Only if whole `str` matched with the `key`), otherwise, return the `str`. However, I'm getting undefined if it wasn't on the list.

NOTE: I don't want it to wrap the result inside an if/else statement and if `undefined` return the `str`. Any way to do it with a simple tweak?

```
var list = {
    'a': 'aaa',
    'b': 'bbb',
    'aa': 'ccc',
    'bb': 'ddd',
}

var str = 'a'

var newStr = str.replace(new RegExp(str), (a) => list[a])

// This is how it should be if it wasn't a 'var'. But with a `var` ?
// var newStr = str.replace(new RegExp(/str/), (a) => list[a]) 

console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: Any reason to require regex? Or replacement?

Comment: Just a replacement is sufficient.

Comment: I'd say `newStr = list[str] ?? str` is all you need. That's why I wonder about the replacement.

Comment: @VLAZ you mean `||` right?

Comment: @ilkerkaran if the replacement is `""` you'd get back `str` and I don't think it's intended.

Comment: Sigh! See... I told you this is the silliest question I ever asked. I'm becoming overthinking dumb after worked with regex heavily. 

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @VLAZ the answer is just...

`newStr = list[str] || str`

Comment: I said `??` but you can use `||` if you're OK with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ["Nullish coalescing operator `(??)`"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

> **The nullish coalescing operator (`??`)** is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) or [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.
>
> This can be contrasted with the [logical OR (`||`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR), which returns the right-hand side operand if the left operand is *any* [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, not only `null` or `undefined`. In other words, if you use `||` to provide some default value to another variable `foo`, you may encounter unexpected behaviors if you consider some falsy values as usable (e.g., `''` or `0`).

```js
var list = {
    'a': 'aaa',
    'b': 'bbb',
    'aa': 'ccc',
    'bb': 'ddd',
}
var str = 'a'
var newStr = list[str] ?? str;
console.log(newStr)
```